# To have a transluscent background for an android activity?

Tags: android, background, translucency

I wish to have a transluscent background for an activity, so that the previous activity can be seen beneath this activity. Something like a transluscent menu that pops up over a videa being played in the background.

Is this possible? Can you tell me how?

Note:I cannot use the default transluscent theme from android, since I am using my own customised background and theme for my application.

Pls help. Below is my style.xml wherein my_btn and my_list are selectors :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <style name="btnstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item> 
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_btn</item>         
    </style>    
    <style name="liststyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/my_list</item>
    </style> 
    <style name="theme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent"> 
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>   
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/btnstyle</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/liststyle</item>  
    </style>
    </resources>
```

Comment: It seems like android:windowIsTranslucent may hinder orientation changes on some devices.  It certainly did on my Samsung phones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply Translucent theme to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

Comment: Hmmm, I can't do this because I have already applied my own theme customised for all buttons and listviews of my application. Also, I have a specific background image also to be used as background for all my activites. Hence, I cant use the default transluscent theme from android. Any other solution?

Comment: Try to add <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>  to your theme defenition

Comment: It doesnt help :(   I set the background of my LinearLayout to an image. This background makes the window to remain opaque! Also, when I remove this background for the layouts, the window becomes translucent, yes. But my buttons(with another background) remain opaque!

Comment: Create your own transparent background images for LinearLayout and Buttons by setting Opacity in your graphics editor.

Comment: Hmmm, ok! I will do that. But still, I just wonder if there is no means of doing this in android, i.e setting the opacity of images etc.

Comment: hey can we set opacity to the activity theme you have mentioned as i wanted its to 30-50% opaque, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been working with android for a while and not able to help you with that.