# Opening an translucent/dialog activity on top of another activity

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there a way to open a translucent or transparent activity so that you can still see the old activity behind it on the screen?

[Edit] To make the question more clear, I know how to create a transparent activity. The problem is when I start it using an intent, it clears the screen and you cannot see the previous activity.

Here is how I start the activity.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DialogActivity.class); startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821624/androidto-have-a-transluscent-background-for-an-android-activity/3821680#3821680

Comment: Well we have no idea without seeing code of DialogActivity.class and your manifest

Comment: Any solution found? please share.

Comment: I recreated the project from scratch and it started to work fine.

Comment: You can use the following link for the translucent activity,
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612256/4658314](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612256/4658314)