# Is it possible to display a bundled Android app within a Unity 3D scene?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

If I have a 2D Android app, which has been bundled with my Unity Android app, is it possible to take this app and render it inside of a 3D Unity scene?

As in have the app render within a rectangle inside the 3D space?

I have done some research and have found lots of resources for doing this in reverse (running a Unity app inside of an Android app) but not really anything for what I'm proposing here.

I haven't really tried anything, as I'm really not sure where one would even start for this.

My intent is to take an open-source Android app called Termux, and display it within my 3D scene in my Android Unity project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display transparent activity on the another activity without removing previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287525/how-to-display-transparent-activity-on-the-another-activity-without-removing-pre)

Comment: This is not supported in Unity. You can search for plugins but I'm almost sure there isn't something like that. It would be super complicated to make it working.